# Can't change color scheme Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, colors

I was helping a friend with clearing her laptop of some adware and viruses and I run two programs `ADWCleaner` and `Junkware Removal Tool`.

But after that she complained that she couldn't change the Windows 8 color scheme anymore. So I logged in to Teamviewer again and tried what she couldn't accomplish. If she clicks another color scheme it changes back to the default one. Very strange behaviour. I googled this problem but I just couldn't find a solution or someone with the same problem.

Below I added an image where the problem occurs. As you can see the color scheme is set on default now. When I click another it simply changes back to default.
[image: The color auto changes back]

Comment: If you create a new user profile are you able to change the color theme?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and it turned out that I had set to sync my theme settings on my Windows Phone. Once I switched it off I could see the option.